# I want to sort a dictionary with key being month-year

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to sort a dictionary with key being month-year.

Eg: For

`March 2017,January 2018,May 2017` etc.

My dictionary keys should be sorted in this order:

`March 2017,May 2017,January 2018`

What to do ?

Eg:

```
{'February 2017': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}, 
 'March 2018': {'a': 0.0, 'b': 623.79}, 
 'March 2017': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}}
```

NB: Values of Month Year comes **dynamically**.

Comment: Use python3.7, or use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @ukemi : In that question, all key values can easily be sorted.
In my question,the values come dynamically and I have to sort it.
Eg: One value will be in March 2017 and other will be in March 2018.How can I sort those ?

Comment: @RafaelC : It works.. Thanks mate..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861179/python-sort-ordereddict-keys-chronologically

Comment: Note that you can't store different values with the same key in python dict.

Comment: @ukemi : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861179/python-sort-ordereddict-keys-chronologically  yes this a possible duplicate .

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the keys into dates so they will sort properly. Assuming your dictionary is called `example_dict`

```
import datetime
keys = list(example_dict.keys())
keys.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%B %Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use special key function for sorting:

```
months = ['January',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

month_num = dict(zip(months, range(12)))


def compare(date):
    month, year = date.split(' ')
    return (year, month_num[month])


dates = {
    'February 2017': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01},
    'March 2018': {'a': 0.0, 'b': 623.79}}

dict(sorted(dates.items(), key=lambda x: compare(x[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), since dictionaries are 'unordered', so to speak, your dictionary in the original post is syntactically incorrect, since there are two keys with the same value. The interpreter will override one of them.

I presumed that one of them should be May 2018, as per your original post, so that is the dictionary I used for my answer:

```
{'February 2017': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}, 
 'May 2018': {'a': 0.0, 'b': 623.79}, 
 'March 2018': {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}}
```

Since, as stated above, dictionaries are not ordered obviously (hash values), so we must convert to a list and then play around. A one liner solution is as follows:

```
sorted(list(data.items()), key=lambda x: [x[0].split()[-1], x[0].split()[0], x[1]])
```

You get the output as follows:

```
>>> sorted(list(data.items()), key=lambda x: [x[0].split()[-1], x[0].split()[0], x[1]])
[('February 2017', {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}), ('March 2018', {'a': 1.0, 'b': 683.01}), ('May 2018', {'a': 0.0, 'b': 623.79})]
>>>
```